# running XSLT throws XPTY0019 error

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I have following XSLT construction:

```
<xsl:template match="list">
        <xsl:param name="tree"/>
        <xsl:param name="accountStatement"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="AccountStatementDetail">
            <tr class="rowNormal">
                <td width="4%" align="center">
                    <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
                </td>
                <td width="4%">
                    <xsl:value-of select="entryDate"/>
                </td>
                <td width="4%">
                    <xsl:value-of select="valueDate"/>
                </td>
                <td width="17%">
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat(ISOBankTransactionCode/ISOBankTransactionCode/domainCode, ' ', ISOBankTransactionCode/ISOBankTransactionCode/familyCode, ' ', ISOBankTransactionCode/ISOBankTransactionCode/subFamilyCode)"/>
                </td>
                <td width="17%">
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat(ISOBankTransactionCode/ISOBankTransactionCode/proprietary/Proprietary/code, ' ', ISOBankTransactionCode/ISOBankTransactionCode/proprietary/Proprietary/issuer)"/>
                </td>
                <td width="17%" align="right">
                    <xsl:value-of select="signedAmount/MonetaryValue/amount"/>
                </td>
                <td width="3%">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$accountStatement/account/Account/currency"/>
                </td>
                <td width="17%">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$tree"/>
                    <xsl:value-of select="accountServicingInstitutionReference"/>
                </td>
                <td width="17%">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$tree"/>
                    <xsl:value-of select="referenceForAccountHolder"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="not(string-length(informationDetail/InformationDetail/messageZone) = 0)">
                    <tr class="rowNormal">
                        <td width="4%"/>
                        <td colspan="8" width="96%" class="fixedWidth">
                            <xsl:value-of select="informationDetail/InformationDetail/messageZone"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="count(AccountStatementDetailAccountStatementMessageDetail/list/AccountStatementMessageDetail) > 0">
                    <tr class="rowNormal">
                        <td width="4%"/>
                        <td colspan="8" width="96%" class="fixedWidth">
                            <xsl:for-each select="AccountStatementDetailAccountStatementMessageDetail/list/AccountStatementMessageDetail">
                                <xsl:choose>
                                    <xsl:when test="not(position() = 1)">
                                        <br/>
                                    </xsl:when>
                                </xsl:choose>
                                <xsl:value-of select="information"/>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="not(string-length(supplementaryDetails) = 0)">
                    <tr class="rowNormal">
                        <td width="4%"/>
                        <td colspan="8" width="96%" class="fixedWidth">
                            <xsl:value-of select="supplementaryDetails"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="count(AccountStatementDetailAccountStatementFreeMessageDetail/list/AccountStatementFreeMessageDetail) > 0">
                    <tr class="rowNormal">
                        <td width="4%"/>
                        <td colspan="8" width="96%" class="fixedWidth">
                            <xsl:for-each select="AccountStatementDetailAccountStatementFreeMessageDetail/list/AccountStatementFreeMessageDetail">
                                <xsl:choose>
                                    <xsl:when test="not(position() = 1)">
                                        <br/>
                                    </xsl:when>
                                </xsl:choose>
                                <xsl:value-of select="information"/>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="ParentStatementDetailAccountStatementDetail/list">
                <xsl:with-param name="tree">&#160;\_&#160;</xsl:with-param>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
```

When I run this XSLT in my Java code, I get an XpathExpressionException, with the error message:

> Caused by: net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: Required item type of
>   first operand of '/' is node(); supplied value has item type xs:string

With some debugging I found following error code, I looked up some information and add it:

> err:XPTY0019
>
> ```
> It is a type error if the result of a step (other than the last step) in a path expression contains an atomic value.
> ```

If I'm right the only atomic value I use is: "$accountStatement/account/Account/currency".

But what is wrong about this?

Comment: change `$accountStatement/account` to `*[local-name()=$accountStatement]/account`

Comment: @JoelMLamsen You seem to be assuming that `$accountStatement` holds an element name. You might be right, but if so you have fantastic deductive powers. Since the type of $accountStatement is not declared, and since we can't see the code that sets its value, we have no way of knowing what's in there.